# web.xml exclusive url-pattern

Tags: java, security, servlets, url-pattern

I want to restrict access to the whole application
    `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`
But not to some Servlets. They should be public.

Is there a way to do that easily (I imagine some exclusion or maybe overriding?) or do I have to arrange files in subfolders and allow access to one while restricting to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is there a way to do that easily (I imagine some exclusion or maybe overriding?)*

No.

---

> *or do I have to arrange files in subfolders and allow access to one while restricting to the other?*

Yes.